# What are the essential rituals for a wedding according to Hinduism?

Tags: rituals, marriage, samskara

This wiki article discusses the various aspects of [marriage in Hinduism.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marriage_in_Hinduism)

According to Hinduism, what are the necessary and sufficient rituals for a wedding?

e.g. Is [Saptapadi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11804/what-are-the-saptapadi-or-the-seven-promises-of-marriage) an essential ritual or just a recommended one?