# Which scripture explains Sapta padi mantra used in Hindu marriage?

Tags: scripture, marriage

There are seven mantras recited during Hindu marriage ritual. Each mantra is recited with each encirclement around fire by bride and bridegroom together. It is said that they take oath in front of Agni god to live together happily and to perform duties enunciated in mantras. But looking at mantra where the term 'bhava'  is used in every mantra, it conveys the meaning - 'to become' like different forms of Agni ; starting with "Ish eka padi' which resemble  with 'ajA eka pAt' which is RigVedic connotation for Sun; and also the second one - 'urja' the energy. Since oath is taken before Agni not before any other god, it seems to be a Vedic ritual of marriage where Agni is first and foremost god. The following are those mantras:-

1. Om Ish eka padi bhava
2. Om urje dvi padi bhava
3. Om rayo poshan tri padi bhava
4. Om maayo bhavya chatus padi bhava
5. Om prajambha panch padi bhava
6. Om ritumbha sat padi bhava
7. Om sakhe sapt padi bhava

It appears that there is no scripture explaining  these mantra as described [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11804/what-are). However many scriptures are aware of these mantras. Since marriage is a regular affair for priests, it might be possible that these mantra persisted and carried forward through the memory of officiating priests like RigVeda.

My question here is - Can we provide literal interpretation of these mantras to explain 'what is it'?

Comment: Piease, bring in original sanskrit mantras if possible.

Comment: Related: [What are the Saptapadi or seven promises of marriage?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/11804/277)

Comment: @Pandya  I visited the site. There seems to be no explanation is found in scripture, better I re- format  my question in this light.

Comment: Did you check the [PDF link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6dS6102zcBgVjdVTndBeDlfaHM/view?usp=sharing) in [my answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/11816/2995)?

Comment: Not really a circumambulation but a step for each mantra.