# What is the significance of bride leading the groom during Saptapadi?

Tags: marriage, women, dharma-shastras, symbolism

This question has nothing to do with feminism or anything else. In Vedic or Hindu religion every step has deep meaning or significance. I know the significance of sacred oaths taken during [Saptapadi](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11804/what-are-the-saptapadi-or-the-seven-promises-of-marriage). But during Saptapadi while walking around the fire (Agni deva) why does the bride always walk first before bridegroom?

It would be great to know the significance of bride leading the groom from scriptures. Please do not give self-made explanations.

---

Note: This is not a duplicate of *[What are the Saptapadi or the seven promises of marriage?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11804/what-are-the-saptapadi-or-the-seven-promises-of-marriage)* which is a general question and doesn't deal with the specific question asked here.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma 
 Please read my questions carefully and do not comment randomly :) Thank you anyway.

Comment: Read the answers carefully. Significance is also added. If it's not what you are looking for, [edit] how it's not different. What type of significance are you looking for? It is a broader term.

Comment: Not duplicate of "What are the Saptapadi or the seven promises of marriage?" It can be related to that question but is seeking more clarifications. Hence leave open.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma 
I already know what is the significance of "saptapadi". I want to know why during saptapadi bride walks before bridegroom. I do not know how to make the question more simple. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Oh! Does bride (female) lead the way? As far as I know, the groom (male) walks before the bride and bride follows him.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma  As far as I have seen  bride walks before the bridegroom. But of course rituals very from place to place. So this is not fixed? who can walks before whom? Bride before bridegroom and the vice versa.

Comment: Bridegroom walks first. Bride follows next. I have never heard or seen what you said. Husband walks before wife. This is fixed anywhere. You might want to edit where you saw this.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I have seen in west bengal and in Bangladesh. However it seems bridegroom walking before the bride is correct rituals. I also researched on that. You can flag this as resolved. I thank you for your kind patience :)

Comment: @Makau if you find the answer on your own, you can post self-answer also.