# What is the purpose of marriage?

Tags: scripture, puranas, philosophy, belief, evidence

Is it to get rid off loneliness, to attain lustfulness, to have more commitment, sacrifice, inheritance, safeguard wealth and oneself? Or what exactly?

People do get married before these questions raise during their early age. Parents don’t give any options to their kids to think before getting married.

Need to understand in Hindu ideology, is marriage essential and mandatory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does our scripture say about marriage? Why should we marry?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/7892/what-does-our-scripture-say-about-marriage-why-should-we-marry)

Comment: Beings are immortal souls packed within 5 elemental material bodies taking birth in ambiance and circumstances based on their previous accumulated Karmas.What do you think will happen to majority common pitra dead souls who dont attain enlightenment or were not corrupt enough to be devolved into insects? They will have to reincarnate again on earth, marriage and its product children is the way of materializing ancestral souls so that they can continue their Karma cycle and contribute to existence through it. Humans are their own ancestors, evolving-devolving over yugas and personal karmas.

Comment: https://www.holy-bhagavad-gita.org/chapter/2 BG 2.12: Never was there a time when I did not exist, nor you, nor all these kings; nor in the future shall any of us cease to be. BG 4.5: Both you and I have had many births, O Arjun. You have forgotten them, while I remember them all, O Parantapa.

Comment: I have closed the Q. Did not realise before casting the vote that my vote is enough to close the Q (since I have a gold scripture badge and this Q is tagged with scripture). So do you agree with the closure? If you are unsatisfied then please post a comment here pinging me.